# Service Pack to SQL Server Container

Tags: sql-server, windows, docker, containers

Is it possible to apply service pack or hotfix to a Container SQL Instance.

I think, we should be creating a new Container image from a patched SQL Instance.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One generally does not patch containers but builds them from the exact tool version one wants - and recreates them on updates.